# C# MVC: What is a good way to prevent Denial Of Service (DOS) attacks on ASP.NET sites?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, denial-of-service

I'm looking for a good and inexpensive way to prevent denial of service attacks on my ASP.NET MVC site.

I've been thinking about a solution that intercepts the HttpHandler and then counts requests in the Cache object, with the key being something like "RequestCount_[IpAddressOfRequestClient]" but that seems like it would generate a crazy overhead.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent DoS attack in ASP.NET MVC applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805694/how-to-prevent-dos-attack-in-asp-net-mvc-applications)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might consider trying to throttle the requests. Identify users by IP and/or cookie and limit requests to (say) 1 every two seconds. A human wouldn't notice, but this would slow down a bot considerably.

This helps at the application level (protects your app/database) but it's not a complete solution, as the hits are still coming at the network level.

As a front line of defense I would probably depend on hardware. Many ISPs offer some protection, eg: http://www.softlayer.com/facilities_network_n2.html

Answer (score 3):

This is a very old question, but I hope this reference helps someone else.

Now we are using '**API Protector .NET**' (https://apiprotector.net) to protect our APIs against DoS and DDoS attacks.

It's a library compatible with **MVC, WebApi and .NetCore** too, that has given us **very good results**, both in **simplicity**, but fundamentally in **maintainability**. With this lib you can protect each function of your API litterally with a single line, and in a very specific way.

As is explained in the website of API Protector .NET:

> If you limit your API, in general way, to N requests per IP or per
>   user, it is enough for these N requests can be used to constantly
>   impact the same specific heavy function that can severely slow down
>   the entire service.
>
> “Each function of your API must be restricted in a
>   particular way depending on the normal frequency of use and the cost
>   of processing which that function implies for the server, otherwise
>   you are not protecting your API.”
>
> API Protector .NET allows you to protect each function of your .NET
>   API against DoS and DDoS attacks without effort, in a simple,
>   declarative and maintenable way.

The only negative point is that **it costs USD 5**, but it gave us what we was looking for at a very low price, unlike the WebApiThrottle library that although it was the first option I tried (because it is free), it ended up being impractical unmaintainable when we wanted to protect different functions in a specific way (which is critical for effective protection, as explained).

API Protector .NET allows to combine different protections (by ip, by user, by role, in general, etc) decorating **each function with a single line**, which makes it **easy to implement and maintain**. For a detailed explaination read: [https://apiprotector.net/how-it-works](https://apiprotector.net/how-it-works/)

An interesting anecdote is that time ago, **when we still protecting our APIs with WebApiThrottle**, we did some tests simulating DDoS attacks, with many parallel requests from different hosts, and for some reason, (I think that is due to something related to thread synchronization), bursts of requests came in to the functions, and late with the server already overloaded, the throttling started. This, added to the difficult maintainability, did not give us too much confidence for a solid protection, and that's why we ended up trying this alternative that works well.

Comment: I can no longer find any references to API Protector .NET anywhere online and the links provided are broken. Can anyone suggest a currently available alternative?